# Remove Enforcement в DOCX (Java)

Tags: java, zip, docx

Окей, привет всем, ребят. Возможно поможете мне.
Есть файл DOCX с защитой по паролю и мне нужно вытащить текст внутри него.
Я могу убирать защиту двумя способами:

1. Конвертить DOCX->XML в WORD, блокнотом вырезат тэг(w:enforcement), открывать XML в WORD, сохранять как DOCX, PROFIT;
2. Распаковать документ ZIPом,вырезать блокнотом w:enforcement в word/settings.xml, запаковать обратно в DOCX, PROFIT;

Однако, мне нужно это делать в программе на Java. Я нашел 2 способа и 2 проблемы, связанные с ними:

1. Использовать removeProtectionEnforcement. Ничего не происходит, доумент отается защищенным;
2. Вручную через ZipEntry. Вот мой код:

Main.java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().removePassword();
    }


    static String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
        java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
        return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
    }

    public void removePassword() {
        ZipOutputStream zos = null;
        try {
            ZipFile zipFile = null;
            try {
                zipFile = new ZipFile("test.docx");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("out.docx"));
            String fileName = "out.docx";
            for (Enumeration e = zipFile.entries(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
                ZipEntry entryIn = (ZipEntry) e.nextElement();

                if (!entryIn.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("word/settings.xml")) {
                    zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(entryIn.getName()));
                    InputStream is = zipFile.getInputStream(entryIn);
                    String read = convertStreamToString(is);
                    zos.write(read.getBytes(), 0, read.length());
                } else {
                    zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(entryIn.getName()));

                    InputStream is = zipFile.getInputStream(entryIn);
                    String read = convertStreamToString(is);
                    System.out.println(read);
                    String oh = read.replaceAll("<w:documentProtection.*?==./>", "");
                    System.out.println(oh);
                    zos.write(oh.getBytes(), 0, oh.length());
                }

                zos.closeEntry();
            }
            zos.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                zos.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Как я увидел, код верно убирет тэг  (как я бы делала блокнотом), правильно запаковывает файл в DOCX, я могу открыть его в WORD и он говорит что в документе защиты нет, тексты все на месте. Размер незащищеного файла 23 kB (защищенного - 26 kB). Это нормально? (3 kB разница). Однако файл распарсить в программе так и не удается (хотя текст на месте)

Рассчитываю на вашу помощь. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

А в документе находится только пустой элемент `w:documentProtection` ?

Просто у него существуют атрибуты (например, `w:algorithmName`, который отвечает за кодирование документа) и тогда разница +/-3 Кб вполне обоснована.

Answer (score 1):

Переупаковка zip с другой степенью сжатия с лёгкостью изменит размер даже если содержимое вообще не менялось.

А правильность работы кода было бы проще проверить, распаковав оба файла обычным архиватором и сравнить содержимое в какой-либо программе, например, WinMerge.